# SSIS data load truncates values into destination table

Tags: ssis, loading, etl, data-conversion, vertica

I have an SSIS package with a simple Source(vertica query) and Destination (sql DB). When I load the data my data values are cut off.

For example, I have a Country code and this is listed as "C" instead of "CN" . I tried to put a DATA CONVERSION and change the data type to DT_STRING, which normally works, but this time it doesn't seem to do anything. Any idea on how I can handle these truncation's. I have mapped the field lengths all the same from source to destination.

Comment: Figure out where the truncation is happening and fix that by using data viewers. Truncation of this type usually results in an error.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " I have mapped the field lengths all the same from source to destination."?   Where did you do this mapping?

Comment: KeithL: There is no error, it just loads partial date into the destination. I normally get an error when there is a mismatch between source and destination data types, but im not getting that now.

Comment: @TabAlleman , in the Data conversion tool .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the `Advanced Properties` of the Source component, and go into each of the `Output Columns` that has truncated data, and set the `Length` property of each of those columns to the maximum possible length that the data in that column can be.

Also take out your data conversion component, since you shouldn't need it and it might interfere with the results of the above change.